# changing values of one select box while another select box clicked in php using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i have a simple form where when a user selects a selectbox another selectbox will show values based on it, its a simple PHP page, so I just did it with the two selectbpxes in a simple page and its working fine as you can see here:

[enter link description here](https://www.modelzworld.com/admin-modelz/testme.php)

now I implemented it in my actual form in the website which is live here:

[enter link description here](https://www.modelzworld.com/admin-modelz/addmodelimages)

however this is giving me blank values, the codes are like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#type").change(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val == "2") {
              $("#size").html("<?php
                  $ret = mysqli_query($con, "select * from modelssubcat where cat_id='2'");

                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {

                    ?
                    > < option value = '<?php echo $row["subcat_name"];?>' > <?php echo $row["subcat_name"];?> < /option><?php }?>");
                  } else if (val == "3") {
                    $("#size").html("<?php
                        $ret = mysqli_query($con, "select * from modelssubcat where cat_id='3'");

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {

                          ?
                          > < option value = '<?php echo $row["subcat_name"];?>' > <?php echo $row["subcat_name"];?> < /option><?php }?>");

                        } else if (val == "4") {
                          $("#size").html("<?php
                            $ret = mysqli_query($con, "select * from modelssubcat where cat_id='4'");

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {

                              ?
                              > < option value = '<?php echo $row["subcat_name"];?>' > <?php echo $row["subcat_name"];?> < /option><?php }?>");

                            } else if (val == "5") {
                              $("#size").html("<?php
                                $ret = mysqli_query($con, "select * from modelssubcat where cat_id='5'");

                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {

                                  ?
                                  > < option value = '<?php echo $row["subcat_name"];?>' > <?php echo $row["subcat_name"];?> < /option><?php }?>");

                                }
                              });


                          });
```

```html
<?php
session_start();


   include("inc/connection.php");
?>


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" class="loading">
  ...........

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-block">

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Category Name</label>



            <select id="type" class="form-control" name="cat_id">
              <option>--Select Category--</option>
              <?php




       
$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from modelscat");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {

?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>">
                  <?php echo $row['cat_name'];?>
                </option>

                <?php }?>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">SubCategory Name</label>
            <select id="size" class="form-control" name="subcat_id">
              <option>--Select Subcategory--</option>





            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        .................
```

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that your $con is a valid db connection ?

Comment: @KenLee yes bro, the first select option is coming from database only, its coming properly

Comment: Close the connection by using `mysqli_close($con);` before you do the next connection/query and see the result.

Comment: In general you should not use SQL queries in loops, it has a bad runtime performance. Instead use JOINs to combine tables and only fire a single query.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz ok bro